# pair of item price under budget

Tags: python, binary-search

I was trying to practice the binary search.
The aim is to find the pair of item prices under budget.

```
def binary_search(arr, lo, hi, x):
    while lo < hi: 
        count = 0
        sum = arr[lo] + arr[hi]
        if sum <= x:
            result = [arr[lo], arr[hi]]
            print(result)
            count += 1
            return binary_search(arr, lo, hi-1, x)
        else:
            return binary_search(arr, lo, hi-1, x)

A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
print(binary_search(A, 0, len(A)-1, 10))
```

As you can see, I can only find the first item with the others:

```
(1,8)
(1,7)
(1,6)
(1,5)
(1,4)
(1,3)
(1,2)
```

of course, I can do it again using

```
return binary_search(arr, lo+1, hi, x)
```

in the function to find the other pairs, but it's not ideal.

or I can use the itertools in a very easy way.

```
from itertools import combinations
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
budget = 10
comb = combinations(A, 2)
answer = []

for i in list(comb):
    if sum(i) <= 10:
        print(I)
        answer.append(i)
print(len(answer))
print(answer)
```

Is there any better ways to deal with this using binary search. Any helps are highly appreciated!